# How can I read the AE figures?

Tags: modes-of-operation, authenticated-encryption

This question is rather simple.

I've recently read the paper

["Automated Analysis and Synthesis of
Authenticated Encryption Schemes"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/624.pdf).

On page 17 of this paper the authors provide three figures of encryption modes for

*tweakable* block ciphers. However all I can see is that the box representing the block cipher

only has one input and one output, as opposed to two for tweakable block ciphers.

Question: **How can I translate the figures into the standard description of modes?**

Standard description means something like $C_1=E_K(M_1\oplus C_0)$ for CBC.

For everyone not sure which figure is meant, here are the figures in question:

[image: Figure in question from cited paper, p. 17]

Comment: I think the tweak (e.g. just a counter) is already supposed to be in there, otherwise scheme 2 would violate CPA (if $M_1 = M_3$ it would clearly show up as $C_1 = C_3$, and authentication would be vulnerable for similar reasons).

Comment: So personally I would go for something like $C_1 = E_{k,1}(M_1 \oplus C_0)$